# adding data with PHP to the db is not working

Tags: php, sql, database, mamp

I'm using MAMP an my PHP won't add data to the db

I have looked at other similar questions and done everything on them, yet it still is not working.
I am using MAMP and I've done everything right as far as I know but the problem is the same no matter what I do.

```
<?php

    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $message = $_GET['message'];

    $my_query = "";

    $my_query = "select * from Users where email = '$email' ";

        $my_query = "INSERT INTO Users (email, name, message) VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$message')";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $my_query );

        if($result)
        {
            echo  "Successfully Sent!";

        }

        else
        {
            echo "<b>ERROR: unable to post </b>";

        } 
    }

    mysqli_close();

?>
```

Comment: Post your error, if you're getting any

Comment: You are using multiple same variables `$my_query` correct the variables name first and post the error, `echo $my_query;` and directly run it in the PHPMYADMIN.

Answer (score 0):

Here use this code and and tell what is the error

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform a query, check for error
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Users (email, name, message) VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$message')"))
{
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

if you dont get any error or blank value in db use your values like

```
values('".$email."', '".$name."', '".$message."')"
```

in db It will be executed like values('test.abc.com', 'abc', 'It is working')